# Alarm Manager&Broadcast receiver not stopping

Tags: android, broadcast, alarm, receiver

I can't stop the alarm manager or broadcast receiver. Any idea to solve this?

Many thanks in advance. By the way I'm using switch button for alarm on/off.

Here is my code;

**MainActivity.class**

```
public void setAlarm(Calendar alarmCalender)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalender.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}

public void cancelAlarm()
{

    AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    aManager.cancel(pIntent);
    stopService(intent);
}
```

**Switch button:**

```
bolme1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean aktiflestirmisse)
            {
                if(aktiflestirmisse)
                {
                    setAlarm(calSet);
                    btn1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.aktifdurum));
                    Toast t= Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Bölme 1 aktif hale getirildi.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                }

                else
                {
                    cancelAlarm();
                    btn1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pasifdurum));
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bölme 1 pasif hale getirildi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                }
```

**In any case here is my AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
NotificationManager manager;
private final int NOTIFICATION_ID =1;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager mng=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.Builder nb=new Notification.Builder(context);
    nb.setContentTitle("Hatırlatma");
    nb.setContentText("İlgili bölmenin vakti ilaç vakti geldi!");
    nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alarm_uyari);
    nb.setTicker("Bildiriminiz var.");
    nb.setAutoCancel(true);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,NOTIFICATION_ID,intent,0);
    nb.setContentIntent(pi);
    Notification not=nb.getNotification();
    not.vibrate=new long[]{500,500,500,500};
    mng.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,not);

    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null)
    {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code for my own app:

Create the pending intent and wrap our intent:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//get the alarm manager
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
{
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
}
else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
{
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
}
else alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

Cancel:

```
private void cancelAlarm(long id)
{
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int)id, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
```

So in your case this will probably work for setting the alarm

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalender.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: yeah, it also makes sure the device wakes up on marshmallow, it's tricky with doze

Comment: But I get error on 'id' variable. I mean, I'm gonna call cancelAlarm(0) or (1) ?

Comment: you have to pass an id to tell the alarmmanager which alarm has to be canceled. Also you should pass PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT when setting the alarm and i think that request code should be replaced by your id (=0 in your case)

Comment: could you write setAlarm properly? Cause I dont get it. What is id? Where should I define that?

Comment: Which means I will call cancelAlarm(0) like this?

Comment: Id is just a number you choose to find it again for canceling it

Comment: also delete the call to stopservice when cancelling the alarm, it's unnecessairy

Comment: Yeeees that's it! Thank you mate. I tried this code 2 times on simulator and it worked out well Thank you again. And I'm gonna ask you 2 question? 1)The alarm is not running exact time. I mean. I set 21:27 but alarm is running 10 sec after 21:27. Is it normal situaiton? 2)I will use 4 alarm on/off actually. And gonna use those with switch button too. Which method I should follow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1)The alarm is not running exact because you need the SetExact() and SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle methods on specific versions of Android, like in my example. 2) for multiple alarms you should use a local database, but if you're sure that you will use only 4 alarms you could just set the alarm id's to 0,1,2,3

Comment: How should I set alarm id? Could you write that with an example?

Comment: the id is the second parameter in the getBroadcast() method, in your case it is 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your cancel alarm button:

```html
public void cancelAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        aManager.cancel(pIntent);
}
```

There is no need for the stopService; once you pass .cancel through to the AlarmManager it will cancel the service via the broadcast.  To check that it is cancelled run in the terminal 'adb shell dumpsys alarm' then search by your package name.  sometimes using findstr or similar to search for the alarm in the terminal won't show the actual alarm but only the history of alarms/wakeups.

Let me know if this works!  :)

Comment: I assume I should define public final int REQUEST_CODE=1 in AlarmReceiver ?

Comment: Yes you can set it to any number as an identifier

Comment: Any number? should I define  final int REQUEST_CODE=1 or 0?

Comment: Just use REQUEST_CODE=1 and if you ever have any other alarms use a different number.

Comment: This code block is working too. But when I set alarm on then off then on, this code is getting error on REQUEST_CODE.

Comment: But it's working. It's cancelling the alarm. Thanks mate! :)